# Programmatically retrieve the sidebar/s classes

Tags: plugins, sidebar

For my new plugin which I develop, I need some code to retrieve the sidebar/s classes(programmatically of caurse).
Can someone advise please?
Regards
I. sher

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [`register_sidebar()`](http://queryposts.com/function/register_sidebar/) source it just stores data in `$wp_registered_sidebars` global variable.

You could examine it and retrieve data from it as you need to.

Comment: Thanks but as I wrote its a plugin and while in developing it, I don't know what will be the enviroment of the wordpress site on real time running in the user's site. I guise I need  some hook but don't know which and how. Regards

Comment: In any case this should be programmatically somehow...

Comment: How do you see it being a plugin preventing you from accessing the global variable and data in it?

Comment: Ok. I'm going to check it. Thx in the meantime...